# How to solve "protoc did not exit cleanly"?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, protocol-buffers

I am compiling this project [googleplaycrawler](https://github.com/Akdeniz/google-play-crawler)

but Eclipse keep complaining

> protoc did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information. (com.google.protobuf.tools:maven-protoc-plugin:0.3.1:compile:default:generate-sources)

BELOW is `pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.akdeniz</groupId>
<artifactId>googleplaycrawler</artifactId>
<version>0.3</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Google Play Crawler</name>
<url>https://github.com/Akdeniz/google-play-crawler</url>

<description>Play with Google Play API :)</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.argparse4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>argparse4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
        <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>protoc-plugin</id>
        <url>http://sergei-ivanov.github.com/maven-protoc-plugin/repo/releases/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.cli.googleplay</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <protocExecutable>protoc</protocExecutable>
                <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/protobuf/</protoSourceRoot>
                <languageSpecifications>
                    <LanguageSpecification>
                        <language>JAVA</language>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    </LanguageSpecification>
                </languageSpecifications>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The Error Message:

```
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:165)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:661)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:366)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:165)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:609)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:565)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:551)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:865)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:120)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystem
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: What is the output of `protoc`? Presumably it printed an error.

Comment: Where did you download the **protoc** binary from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by change maven3.2 to maven3.0.5!

Answer (score 1):

I had this error thanks to my antivirus (BitDefender). It blocked protoc-windows.exe. The funny part is that even adding the executable to the exception list, it still didn't recognize it as an exception, it recognized it as a new executable...This is so frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your proto files are valid

The error solved when I delete generated java files and unfinished proto file

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem arose due to the fact that on the path to the folder in which my project was located in the tree there were folders not in English and the path was not clear. After I put my project in a folder on the "C" drive C:\Projects , everything immediately started working

Answer (score 1):

I solverd this problem by updating version of "pluginArtifact" in the configuration of plugin. The version of "pluginArtifact" didn't meet to the version of the grpc dependencies.
My grpc dependencies have version 1.53.0 but my pluginArtifact was 1.23.0
So I updated pluginArtifact to 1.53.0 and it solved this problem.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>1.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.53.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: in my case ${os.detected.classifier} solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The plugin com.google.protobuf.tools:maven-protoc-plugin:0.3.2 's repository is invalid. so need change the repository url.

the pom pluginRepositories segement is follow:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>protoc-plugin</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xolstice/maven/plugins/protobuf-maven-plugin/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

the pom plugin segement is follow:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.2</version>

            <configuration>
                <protocExecutable>E:\Program\protoc-2.5.0\protoc.exe</protocExecutable>
                <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/protobuf/</protoSourceRoot>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/protobuf/java/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```